# How to override List<T> Add method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following as a way to denormalize a list of integers:

```
public string DbUsersMessaged { get; set; }

public List<int> UsersMessaged {
    get {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(DbUsersMessaged) ? new List<int>() : DbUsersMessaged.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
    }
    set {
        DbUsersMessaged = value != null ? String.Join(",", value) : null;
    }
}
```

To read, I can query `sersMessaged.Contains(id)`.

To write, I'd like to simply do `UsersMessaged.Add(id)`, but this doesn't work because `set` isn't called.

For now, I'm doing this to trigger the `set`:

```
UsersMessaged = UsersMessaged.AddReassign(user);
public static List<int> AddReassign(this List<int> list, int item)
{
    var tempList = list;
    if (list.Contains(item))
        return list;
    tempList.Add(item);
    list = tempList;
    return list;
}
```

But this is not ideal because I have `AddReassign` throughout.  Ideally I can just use `Add`.  Per another answer, I know I can override the `Add` method via the following:

```
public class DbList : List<int>
{
  public override void Add(int value)
  {
    // AddReassign logic goes here
  }
}
```

However I have some questions:

- How can I move my logic into the overridden `Add`?  I've been struggling with syntax for a while.
- How would `get` change in the above?  I know I need to return a `DbList`, but how do I cleanly instantiate a `DbList` from an `IEnumerable`?
- Is there any simple way to make this solution generic, instead of just for `int`?

Comment: Write a class that inherits from `List<T>`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan that's what I'm struggling with - per the three bullets at the bottom.

Comment: Use composition, not inheritance.

Comment: @Servy googling now.  If anyone has time to demonstrate their preferred approach, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt?rq=1

Comment: A couple options: 1) Rather than `List<int>` you could use `ObservableCollection<int>` and listen for additions and removals yourself, OR 2) Rather than maintaining both the list and the string, maintain just the list and recreate the string as required.

Comment: I guess you could do it a bit like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iX5lHL

Comment: @SB2055 Did the .net fiddle help you?

Comment: @Icepickle I tried doing what you've outlined there but I'm getting stuck trying to apply it to my code.  I'll try to make a dotnetfiddle to reproduce for you but it probably won't be today.  Feel free to make an answer and I can accept it - any help demoing `get` etc would be nice

Answer (score -1):

Inherit and shadow, like this:

```
class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        if (!this.Contains(item)) base.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Any methods of the ancestor class that call `Add` will still call the old version of `Add` (i.e. there is no polymorphism here), but any of your code that uses the class will call the new version of `Add`, which will prevent duplicates using the logic you provided.

If you already have a bunch of List<> objects and need to convert them to MyList, add a static "From" method, like this:

```
class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    ...
    static public MyList<T> FromList(List<T> source)
    {
        MyList<T> newList = new MyList<T>();
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            newList.Add(item);
        }
        return newList;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not overriding the method.  That's shadowing it, and the actual `List` method will still be callable.